# Ansible playbook to test SSH connections

Tags: ansible

I would like to run a playbook that tests SSH connections for few Linux users.

Example: 
user1: Bob password: Test12345
user2: Alice password: Test123

How can I write a playbook to check if the above credentials works on a host?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> ***I would like to run a playbook that tests SSH connections for few Linux users.***

according the documentation there is a

[`ping` module – Try to connect to host, verify a usable python and return pong on success](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ping_module.html)

> *... test module, this module always returns `pong` on successful contact. It does not make sense in playbooks, but it is useful from `/usr/bin/ansible` to verify the ability to login and that a usable Python is configured.*

which seems exactly be doing what you are looking for.

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to check SSH access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73647690/6771046)

Answer (score -1):

I didn't test this playbook but it should give you a nice idea.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test_users:
      bob: Test12345
      alice: Test123
  tasks:
    - name: Install sshpass package
      package:
        name: sshpass
        state: present
      become: yes

    - name: Test ssh connection for users
      command: sshpass -p {{ item.value }} ssh {{ item.key }}@your-host 'echo success'
      with_dict: '{{ test_users }}'
```

> Also it is not recommended to use SSH with passwords. You should set
>   pub key authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your time on this. I was looking for an option without installing sshpass. But I will try this out.