# Ansible: How to check SSH access

Tags: ssh, ansible

Good morning all,

I'm racking my brains over a simple subject.

I'm on a "master" server and I would like to check if he manages to connect in SSH on a server list.

**Example**

```bash
ansible-playbook -i inventaire_test test_ssh.yml
```

```yaml
---

      tasks:
    
      - name: test unreachable
        ansible.builtin.ping:
        register: test_ssh
        ignore_unreachable: true
    
      - name: test
        fail:
          msg: "test"
        when: test_ssh.unreachable is defined
    
      - name: header CSV
        lineinfile:
            insertafter: EOF
            dest: /home/list.csv
            line: "Server;OS;access"
        delegate_to:localhost
    
      - name: Info
        lineinfile:
            dest: /home/list.csv
            line: "{{ inventory_hostname }};OK"
            state: present
        when: test_ssh is successful
        delegate_to:localhost
    
      - name: Info csv
        lineinfile:
            dest: /home/list.csv
            line: "{{ inventory_hostname }};KO"
            state: present
        when: test_ssh.unreachable is undefined
        delegate_to:localhost
```

I can't find a `check_ssh` module. There is `ansible.builtin.ssh` but I can't use it.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding

> *I'm on a "master" server and I would like to check if he manages to connect in SSH on a server list. ... I can't find a `check_ssh` module.*

According the documentation there is a

[`ping` module – Try to connect to host, verify a usable python and return pong on success](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ping_module.html)

> *... test module, this module always returns `pong` on successful contact. It does not make sense in playbooks, but it is useful from `/usr/bin/ansible` to verify the ability to login and that a usable Python is configured.*

which seems to be doing what you are looking for.