# Ansible: 'ping' Fortigate host results into error 'Unknown action 0'

Tags: ansible

I'm new to Ansible and I'm running into errors.  My goal is to be able to manage Fortigate/Cisco devices.

I created a Ubuntu VM(22.04) with all the necessary packages needed to run Ansible.  I've created a very basic `hosts` file with a firewall group:

```ini
[firewalls]
10.23.60.120
10.23.60.122
```

I've been successful at pinging each of the firewalls as well as using SSH to connect to the firewalls. But once I attempt to ping the firewalls using the `-m ping` module I get the following errors:

```json
ansible -i hosts firewalls -m ping

[WARNING]: Platform unknown on host 10.23.60.120 is using the discovered Python
interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python
interpreter could change the meaning of that path.  See
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-
core/2.13/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
10.23.60.120 | FAILED! => {
 "ansible_facts": {
     "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
  }
 "changed": false,
 "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.23.60.120 closed.\r\n",
 "module_stdout": "TR1-SDWAN-LAB-01 # 8415: Unknown action 0\r\nCommand fail. Return code 
-1\r\n\r\n TR1-SDWAN-LAB-01 # ",
 "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
 "rc": 0
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you made a mistake quoting the error messages. The double-e in "stdeer" that you quoted in your "module_stdeer" error message is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

According the information provided it seems that you try to establish a SSH connection to a switch. Such devices may not have all capabilities for Python scripts.

Because of [`ping` module – Try to connect to host, verify a usable python and return pong on success](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ping_module.html) it

- "*is NOT ICMP ping, ... just a trivial test module that requires Python on the remote-node*"
- is a "*... test module, this module always returns pong on successful contact. It does not make sense in playbooks, but it is useful from /usr/bin/ansible to verify the ability to login and that a usable Python is configured.*"

The Most Significant Information is the error message `Unknown action 0` and which is according [Fortigate Documentation - Command syntax](https://help.fortinet.com/fadc/4-8-0/cli/Content/FortiADC/cli-ref/Command_syntax.htm) just an unknown command

> "*If you do not enter a known command, the CLI will return an error message such as: `Unknown action 0`*"

**Further Background Information**

- Fortinet Ansible Issue #[72](https://github.com/fortinet-ansible-dev/ansible-galaxy-fortios-collection/issues/72) "*Unknown Action 0 when running modules*"

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to check SSH access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73647690/6771046)