# ansible ping module does not work on fortiweb server

Tags: ansible

I tried to install fortios roles on a fortiweb server created on Azure Portal using an image of the marketplace. I can't communicate with it using the adhoc command :

`ansible fortiweb -m ping -i inventory.yml  --extra-vars "ansible_user=administrateur ansible_password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`

I'm not sure, but does my fortiweb server need python ?

The error without the verbose option is :

```
[WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host waf01: unexpected output from Python interpreter discovery
[WARNING]: Platform unknown on host waf01 is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change this. See
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
waf01 | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Parsing error at '/bin/sh'. err=1\n",
    "module_stdout": "fortiwaf01 # Command fail. CLI parsing error.\n\nfortiwaf01 # ",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 0
}
```

I can't display the output command with the verbose option ( -vvvv) because it's considered spam.

I tried to put `ansible_python_interpreter` in ansible.cfg and in inventory.yml but it doesn't work. I've disabled gather_facts in the role.

Comment: Does [Ansible: 'ping' Fortigate host results into error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73955446/6771046) answer your question?